# In order to calculate the determinant of a matrix does it need to be in RREF?

Tags: linear-algebra

Does it matter if a matrix is in RREF before calculating the determinant? I'm still getting two non-zero determinants but I'm wondering if there's a right way.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Changing a matrix to RREF will often change the value of the determinant, so it is not true that the determinant of a matrix is the same as the determinant of its RREF. It is possible to keep track of how the determinant has changed during the RREF calculation though.

Answer (score 0):

There is a property regarding matrix determinants that you may find handy and is as follows. The determinant of the product of two matrices is the product of the determinants of those matrices. In math-speak,

$$ \det(AB)=\det(A)\cdot\det(B)  \text{ .}$$

When you say

> Does it matter if a matrix is in RREF before calculating the determinant?

the answer is of course yes! Any invertible matrix, $A$, when reduced to its RREF, $B$, will have $\det(B)=1$. If you reduce the matrix first, you may write $A$ as the product of "elementary matrices" times the reduced matrix $B$ as

$$A = E_1E_2E_3\dots E_n B\text{ .}$$

You may calculate $\det(A)$ by itself or calculate the determinant of all elementary matrices and the determinant of $B$ (which should be either unity or zero) and compute the product of those determinants.

For future reference, your question is rather vague so if this does not clear things up feel free to comment below.